# Logitech X52 HOTAS not working after suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, input

I have a problem with my Logitech X52 HOTAS, working perfectly under Ubuntu 18.04.
After suspend, the X52 is still detected, but no input is detected anymore (I used joystick and jstest-gtk to monitor this. To install : `sudo apt install joystick jstest-gtk`)
I tried to disable and enable the device by doing this :

```
sudo modprobe -r joydev
```

then

```
sudo modprobe joydev
```

with no success

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my problem by disabling then enabling te device at USB level.

1. Used `lsusb` to identify the Bus and Device of my HOTAS
2. Used `lsusb -t` to identify the port corresponding to the device
3. Tried `echo 'a-b' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` and `echo 'a-b' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` where `a` is the bus number and `b` is the port number --> MY HOTAS WORKED AGAIN !
4. Automated the disable/enable in systemd by

   `sudo touch /lib/systemd/system-sleep/joystick`

   `sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/joystick`

   `sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/joystick`
5. Adding the following script to the previously created file

`#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo '1-2' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
    ;;
  post/*)
    sleep 2
    echo '1-2' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
    ;;
esac`

where `a` is the bus number and `b` is the port number